# PDF import NextJS

Tags: pdf, next.js

I want to import a pdf file and edit it and export it. But if I do import file from '../public/pdf/front.pdf'; I am getting "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)" Please help.

Comment: From what I know, parsing and editing a PDF is very difficult without proprietary software. Converting to PDF or displaying a PDF is probably doable.

Comment: oh thank you, ive done a work around. i just serve the file locally and fetch it then modify it. thanks :D

Comment: did u solve it? I m also stuck